# How to rotate the tab focus within the popup in ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have a popup with some input fields, links and buttons.
When I press tab, then the focus is moving to next element as expected.
After completing all the focus-able fields, tab focus moving to the Parent window's buttons, links, etc...

Is there any workaround to rotate the tab focus within the popup ?

I am working with ADF in JDev 11.1.1.7.0.

Comment: I dont think so. Because I believe the popup is another element in the dom, so the rotation happens through the entire elements in the dom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is ADF framework bug. Hosted a bug with ADF Framework and they have accepted this as a bug.

I'll update this post once I get the resolution from ADF team.